# How to get Index of IEnumerable SelectList?

Tags: c#

I want index from ViewBag and if not possible then From selectedlist but can't get it.

```
ViewBag.Lst_Fetch_Record = new SelectList(list.OrderBy(ITEM_CD => ITEM_CD));
int index = ViewBag.Lst_Fetch_Record.IndexOf("I1");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you an ordered list with indexes

```
    List<string> selectListName = new List<String>();
    selectListName.Add("Ohio");
    selectListName.Add("Maine");
    selectListName.Add("Texas");
    selectListName.Add("Oregon");
    selectListName.Add("Alabama");

var result2  = selectListName.Select( (state, index) => new { index, state  
}).OrderBy(a=>a.state).ToList();        
    foreach(var b in result2)
{ 
  Console.WriteLine( b.index  + " " + b.state) ;
}

result:   If you re looking for the existing index
 4 Alabama
 1 Maine
 0 Ohio
 3 Oregon
 2 Texas

To use the result
Console.WriteLine(result2.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.state.Equals("Ohio")).index);
2
Console.WriteLine(result2.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.index.Equals(2)).state);
Ohio
```

---

```
To get this result: 
0 Alabama
1 Maine
2 Ohio
3 Oregon
4 Texas

 Order first, then index as shown below
   var result2  = selectListName.OrderBy(a=>a).Select( (state, index) => new { index, 
      state  }).ToList();       
    foreach(var b in result2) 
    {
      Console.WriteLine( b.index  + " " + b.state) ;
    }
```

Comment: without for loop can not possible find index of any value?

Comment: I edited the answer. See the "To use the result" section. You really just need result2.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.state.Equals("Ohio")).index  to get your answer.

Comment: in your code error in index. i don't want to display all data so remove for loop but error in index.

Comment: You only need this: var result2  = selectListName.Select( (state, index) => new { index, state  }).OrderBy(a=>a.state).ToList();        
Console.WriteLine(result2.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.index.Equals(2)).state);

Comment: yes but in this error in index because index in not declare so can you please tell me declare to integer or any other?

Comment: everything is right but getting wrong index. index is not change when order by

Comment: this is the right ans please change it in your comment :- result2.IndexOf(result2.Where(p => p.Text == a).FirstOrDefault())

Answer (score 1):

Use this method :

```
ViewBag.Lst_Fetch_Record.Select((item, index) => new 
{
       ...Your Code
}
```

Comment: can not understand your code, what are you trying to said.

Answer (score 1):

Getting Index without using for loop

```
 var result2 = new SelectList(list.OrderBy(ITEM_CD=> ITEM_CD)).ToList();
 INT Index = result2.IndexOf(result2.Where(p => p.Text == a).FirstOrDefault());
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check this example:**

```
class Pet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public static void OrderByEx1()
{
    Pet[] pets = { new Pet { Name="Barley", Age=8 },
                   new Pet { Name="Boots", Age=4 },
                   new Pet { Name="Whiskers", Age=1 } };

    IEnumerable<Pet> query = pets.OrderBy(pet => pet.Age);

    foreach (Pet pet in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", pet.Name, pet.Age);
    }
}
```

Source: Microsoft documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-5.0

Comment: I want index of data which i passed not all data Index and with out loop there is possible?

Comment: You want to sort just a part of a list?

Comment: no after shoritng I want to index of "I1" which is store in  new SelectList(list.OrderBy(ITEM_CD => ITEM_CD))

Comment: I1 is the data which store in ITEM_CD like in your example Boots